# Gradle: detect if there are @Test methods in a particular folder

Tags: android, gradle, testing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to create a gradle method that would return me a `boolean` saying if a `project` passed as input has some tests defined in a particular sub folder. Particularly, I am interested in knowing if the project contains android instrumentation tests.

So far, this is what I have (my root project has multiple sub-projects):

```
def doesProjectContainsInstrumentationTests(project) {
    def rootDir = new File(rootProject.rootDir, "")
    def projectPath = project.getPath().replaceAll(':', '/')
    def fullPath = new File(rootDir, projectPath)
    def androidTestFolder = new File(fullPath, "src/androidTest")
    //TODO: find a better way to detect if the module has instrumentation tests to run (using some annotation like @Test or @RunWith?)
    def containsInstrumentationTests = androidTestFolder.exists()
    return containsInstrumentationTests
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that the folder might exist but no tests are in it. In that situation, the code above would return `true` while it should return `false`.

Ideally I would like to reuse the same logic described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_detection), but not sure I can do it.

Any suggestion on how I could achieve that? I'm ok if there is a completly different way to achieve that, as long as it works :)